# Laravel push in order

Tags: laravel

Hi I am trying to combine two collections in a way that, the difference from the second collection is inserted one by one at the end of the first collection. However, when I try to use diff to find the difference between two collections and push each different set, the order seems to be messed up. Can someone help me with this please?

```
$serviceids = Service::where('service_name', 'like', '% ' . $chip_service . ' %')
            ->orWhere('service_name', 'like', '% ' . $chip_service)
            ->orWhere('service_name', 'like', $chip_service . ' %')
            ->orWhere('service_name', $chip_service)
            ->pluck('service_recordid');

$service_description_all = Service::where('service_description', 'like', '% ' . $chip_service . ' %')
            ->orWhere('service_description', 'like', '% ' . $chip_service)
            ->orWhere('service_description', 'like', $chip_service . ' %')
            ->orWhere('service_description', $chip_service)
            ->pluck('service_recordid');

$service_description = $service_description_all->diff($serviceids)->all();

foreach ($service_description as $key => $ser){
        $serviceids->push($ser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

push function acts like stack, so the first element will be at the end the last in the stack.
you can use directly:

```
$serviceids = $service_description + $serviceids
```

Comment: Object of Collection actually cannot be converted to numbers

Comment: this addition is between arrays , like $bigArray = $array1 + $array2;